# Pattern for Accessing Web Services

Tags: c#, web-services, design-patterns

I need to access a Web-svc, run a bunch of queries and save the data to a store as part of an analysis. On top of this, there is a web-site that will query the datastore and show this data.

We have features like this getiing added every month. How can I reduce the amount of boilerplate code that get's written.

1. Add web svc ref
2. Wrap methods in provider layer to handle exceptions
3. Prepare request
4. Send request
5. Store data locally.
6. Retrive and show data through aspx.

This is such a pain.

Comment: guessing from the tag he is talking about c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found two things useful for lowering the tedious coding of the scenario
- [WCF Line of Business Adapter SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/technologies/wcflobadaptersdk.mspx): This provides a very powerful base for building an WCF adapter (basically like a BizTalk adapter). It is a bit tough the first time but adding to it later is much nicer.
- [p&p Web Service Factory](http://www.codeplex.com/servicefactory): This is nice for the database stuff especially since it provides some great wizards to do automatic generation. Not to say you can't use it for other things.